# unable to make postgres unaccent extension working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

In a working app, I'm trying to implement unaccent query.

```
pg-gem version 0.21
postgresql version 9.5/9.6
rails version 4
```

I first create/enable the extension here is the migration:

```
def up
  execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS unaccent'
end

def down
  execute 'DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS unaccent'
end
```

The migration runs fine. `psql \dx` shows that the extension is on. 
A simple unccent query on `psql` reveals that it's working as expected.

When I try querying something like this:

```
people = people.where('unaccent(people.first_name) ILIKE unaccent(?)', "%#{params[:first_name]}%") if params[:first_name].present?
```

I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function unaccent(character varying) does not exist
```

At first I was thinking that the connexion was made to the wrong database as I played with a lot of versions but after assuring that was not the case, the error still remains.

To be totally sure I also test it on a test server which results with the same error.

As everything seems fine at the db level I suspect something on the rails side but I don't know how to investigate any further.

Any help/suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Perhaps the extension was created in a schema that is not in the `search_path` of your rails application?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was actually reading on this. As we're using appartment gem to make schemas for tenant I think this could be the explanation. Let me check for that and get back to you.

Comment: I was naively thinking that extensions will work for all the schemas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension must have been created in a schema that is not on the `search_path` of the rails application.

The best solution would be to have a `common` schema (or maybe use the existing `public` schema) that contains objects that are common to all schemas. Then install the extension in that schema.

Comment: For those who also use `apartment gem` be sure to double check their docs: https://github.com/influitive/apartment#installing-extensions-into-persistent-schemas

Answer (score 8):

Run a new migration worked for me

```
class AddUnaccent < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    enable_extension "unaccent"
  end
end
```

Then in the query

```
Store.where('unaccent(name) ILIKE unaccent(?)', "%#{term}%")
```

Comment: You didn't use UNACCENT in your query. Try something like `people = people.where('unaccent(people.first_name) ILIKE unaccent(?)', "%#{params[:first_name]}%")`

Comment: `Store.where('unaccent(name) ILIKE unaccent(?)', "%#{term}%")` in your context